# When programming, do you show all errors as message boxes or do you put them in a log file

Tags: vb.net, error-handling

I am trying to develop a standard when I code applications.

I was curious as to what other developers did when it comes to sql errors or general program errors.  Do you output the error to the screen, write to a log file, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on the severity of the error.

- Is it a show stopper?
- Can the software automatically retry and get away with no message?
- Can it be ignored?

You can log every exception, or just certain ones, or none. I have a custom Exception class which logs every exception created (of that type).

I have an unhandled exception handler which emails me when there is one.

I'd only send a message to the user when it will change the way the application works from the user's point of view.

Your question is a bit subjective and you would get opinion-based answers if the entire community bothered to answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the error is relevant and important to the user (e.g.: invalid username/password) display it to the user using a message box.

If the error is relevant to the developer, or can be used in the debugging process, use a log or a console output.

The trick is to identify which and how the errors should be displayed to the user. You don't want to bombard the user with exceptions and complicated errors on which the user has no idea on how to act upon.